# Get partner (including its children) invoices

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

I'm trying to get the first and last invoices for a partner including its children.

Is there any method to get all partner invoices including its children?
Otherwise, how can I get it using SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `child_of` domain operator. So if `partner_id` is the partner you want all invoices of including all invoices of its children, your search domain should look like:

```py
[('partner_id', 'child_of', partner_id)]
```